# Shell commands from Gfortran for Windows?

Tags: windows, shell, fortran, gfortran

I'd like to issue dos-type ("shell") commands from gfortran for Windows, such that that the command finishes executing before the Fortran program does the next step.  I.e. what some call a "shell-and-wait" command.  Ideally the shell command should be a string that can be generated automatically from within the Fortran program.

Is that possible in gfortran for Windows?  If so, how?

Comment: [The Windows command prompt is *NOT* a DOS prompt!](https://scalibq.wordpress.com/2012/05/23/the-windows-command-prompt-is-not-a-dos-prompt/)

Comment: Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all  Fortran  questions.